# Searching through 2D array horizontally, vertically, and diagonally (both directions) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, search, 2d

I am having difficulty with this program I am trying to write. I found many similar problems and solutions online, but they weren't exactly what I was looking for.

There is a text file that my program reads and turns into a char 2D array.

Sample text file:

```
HFELOJF
ESFOIGD
LSDIOGS
LTDMGER
OEROFFT
SFDLKEG
```

Then I give it a word such as "hello", and the program prints out weather or not the word exists in the array. Sort of like a word search.

I need to be able to search horizontally, vertically and diagonally. But the word can also be backwards in all 3 cases.

I have started with 2 for loops that start for the top left and work its way to the end.

Inside the 2nd for-loop I have 3 while-loops to deal with: horizontal, vertical and diagonal text. But I just realized that it doesn't work if the word is in reverse. Now in order for me to fix this, I have to construct 3 other while loops to work with my code.

I just find this very repetitive and think there must be a simpler way. But I have been staring at this problem for hours and haven't come up with a brighter idea.

If I continue with what I have, I would have 2 for-loops and 6 while-loops inside the second for-loop which I find to be very messy and repetitive and extra code. Is there a better, faster and more effective way in doing such a problem?

Appreciate all the help and information I can get!

Comment: If you can find a `String` forward, reverse it and see if it works.

Comment: Yes that would work, but it would require me to make another loop and keep  subtracting from the array to see if it works. I know it works but it doubles the code. I want to see if there is a simpler way of dealing with both cases, forward and reversed.

Comment: "I just find this very repetitive and think there must be a simpler way". Sometimes homework exercises (I'm assuming that's what this is) are meant to be grueling and repetitive, for the purpose of understanding a subject matter.  In this case, the subject matter is traversing 2d arrays.  Yes, the problem sucks, but I'm sure you'll figure out alot on the way to solving it

Comment: Work out all the code you can. If you get stuck, post your code and clearly explain where you got stuck and why.  I'm sure if you do this, you'll get a better response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check the reverse

```
String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually helped quite a bit. What i did previously was take the original string and get the last letter from that and work my way backwards, but that confused things to a new level. I was able to really simplify the code with your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  Loop through each letter.  Pretend that letter is the start or end letter of the word.  So skip it if it is not either 'h' or 'o' in the case of "hello".  Then for each letter check the diagonals, horizontal, and vertical directions. Also if you this whole reverse thing bothers you ignore it.  Just search for the letter 'h' and make sure you check all directions from that letter.